# Isometric Embeddings into Hyperbolic Space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

When can a finite metric space $X$ be isometrically embedded into Hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^{n}$?

It seems there are results for isometric embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ [Maehara 2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2013.08.029) with sufficient dimensions. But I wonder about hyperbolic space.

My motivation comes from trying to embed the leaves of tree-like data in space, a bit like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.00402).